# SpriteKit Networking Physics (Various Devices)

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I am working on a SpriteKit Game, that is networkable.  The problem I am having is that the physics vary on different devices and screen sizes., iPhone 5s, iPhone 6+, iPad Mini 2 Retina, and iPad 2, and MBP 17, and Air 11.

The Players Play on a scene that is defined by this: self an SKScene, gameScene.m.

For various reasons I made the gameScene.sks size 414x414 and createSceneContents using:

```
self.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFit;
self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,0.5);
self.size = CGSizeMake(self.size.width*4, self.size.height*4);
```

I do the *4 because I am going to add zooming up to 1x 2x 4x.

The beginning basics are two creatures that face off.
I set both of their mass and density using:

```
char.physicsBody.density = 1.0;
char.physicsBody.mass = 1.0;
```

I read changing them would fix different device/screen issues (false).

When one is moving at the other I get mixed results when they collide.
On the Mac when ramming the other the (iOS) creature the Mac creature gets stopped and can't budge the other.  The iOS char can ram the Mac creature and pushes him all around.

I went in and changed the mass and density, based on:

The scene takes up a square in the middle of the device so the bounds width is the width of the devices.  What is the golden number I need to put in here to make the iOS devices equal to the Mac devices.

```
// CGFloat result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width //maybe later :)
CGFloat ratio = 414/3000;

char.physicsBody.density = 1.0*ratio;
char.physicsBody.mass = 1.0*ratio;
```

This is just the basic starting point I began with.  The reason is I believe that that SpriteKit is making the objects proportional from screen to screen (bounds to bounds, devices to device).  But it's mainly Mac to iOS that is way off.  Mac to Mac is even in a head butt competition, I don't need to change the mass/density.

The code is in my Xcode.project file and they share the source code, and compile from them.

this block is used to go back and forth:

```
#ifdef IOS_BLOCK
    CGFloat ratio1 = (414.0/3000);
    CGFloat ratio2 = 1;
    _playerChar.physicsBody.mass = _playerChar.physicsBody.mass*ratio1;
    _playerChar.mainThrust = 160*ratio1;
    _playerChar.reverseThrust = 80*ratio1;
    _playerChar.lateralThrust = 0.4*ratio1;

    _opposeChar.physicsBody.mass = _opposeChar.physicsBody.mass*ratio2;
    _opposeChar.mainThrust = 160*ratio2;
    _opposeChar.reverseThrust = 80*ratio2;
    _opposeChar.lateralThrust = 0.4*ratio2;
#else
    CGFloat ratio1 = 1;
    CGFloat ratio2 = (414.0/3000);
    _playerChar.physicsBody.mass = _playerChar.physicsBody.mass*ratio1;
    _playerChar.mainThrust = 160*ratio1;
    _playerChar.reverseThrust = 80*ratio1;
    _playerChar.lateralThrust = 0.4*ratio1;

    _opposeChar.physicsBody.mass = _opposeChar.physicsBody.mass*ratio2;
    _opposeChar.mainThrust = 160*ratio2;
    _opposeChar.reverseThrust = 80*ratio2;
    _opposeChar.lateralThrust = 0.4*ratio2;
#endif
```

NOTE: I change it up in Mac vs Mac or iOS vs iOS to 1:1

This value of 3000 seems to hold things at bay in head butt competitions using joystick vs keyboard vs UIButtons etc.

But my question is what is this ratio's "weight" based on? 414/3000  I mean it could be 500/3000, 1/6 and that would make things fairly close too.

But what is the need for the ratio and why do iOS vs iOS and Mac vs Mac work when 1:1, when iOS to Mac is 6:1? and I have to divide by the ratio.

I was hoping to get everything EQUALIZED on all devices using SpriteKit.
btw the Sprite Sizes are:
102/204/306 (iOS)
and
120/240 (Mac)
Thanks ahead for any help.

Comment: Ok I did some more testing, the 414/3000 head butts equally on iPhone 6 simulator vs Mac, but on smaller devices iPhone 4s/5s or even bigger iPad Air 2 (simulators), the Mac wins the head butting.  I have been going back and forth and trying to find some info online but I am about to start reading again instead of banging...

Comment: I am adding this comment, because I am going nuts a little, because I am trying to sum this up and here is the best way I can sum this question up.  I am getting mixed results with different devices but all in all the Mac to iOS ratio is approximately 1:6 in objects being heavier i.e. harder to move.  When I adjust the factors: thrust and mass I can get things fairly equal but what is the deal?  They share the same source code hmm...

Comment: I read this from the apple documentation: Test your game on real hardware, and on devices with different characteristics. In many cases, the balance of CPU resources and GPU resources are different on each Mac or iOS device. Testing on multiple devices helps you to determine whether your game runs well on the majority of devices.  WOW OK :( bummer, maybe this is answered at that point but, I need a 2nd opinion?

Answer (score 2):

All is about physics lows!
You must notice that when you change device screen size , some things is changing in physics point view.
for example:

Suppose you want apply 100 impulse to a ball with 20 radius and with 1 density.

You see in 5s simulator ball goes faster than 6s or iPad simulator.
Why?

Cause physics!

Let see:

In physic lows the relation of impulse is

> p = mv

Which p is momentum, m is mass, and v is velocity.

Now let have some simple Physics calculations:

> density = m/A (m: mass, A: Area)

We assumed density = 1 So

> m = A = pi*(r)^2 (r: radius)

And we mentioned about momentum:

> p = mv => v = p/m => v = p/(pi*(r)^2)

you applied 100 impulse so

> (p = 100) => v = 100/(pi*(r)^2)

Again I remind that v is velocity and r is radius.
You see

> v ∼ 1/(r^2)

which means v is grows with 1/(r^2)

And this means if you grow your ball physicsBody radius with screen size with constant momentum velocity being reduce!

What about constant radius?

For example you set your ball physicsBody radius to 20 and it never change with screen size.

So :

> v = 100/(pi*(20)^2)

Imagine the velocity being 50 (it's just Assumption not real!)

Means your ball goes in 5s phone 50 point per second and Since the width of 5s is 568 point, the ball goes About (5sWidth)*1/10 per second.

For iPad Air width is 1024 so with the same velocity ball goes about (iPadAirWidth)*1/20 per second.

Which, means velocity being reduce.

You see, puzzle solved!

So you must fit your physics property and screen size when using physics in spriteKit.

Comment: it's true... only so much can be taken care of for us... :D

Comment: @rezwits so please accept my answer, if you think it's helpful

Answer (score 0):

The answer was Apple's Documentation stating:   Test your game on real hardware, and on devices with different characteristics. In many cases, the balance of CPU resources and GPU resources are different on each Mac or iOS device. Testing on multiple devices helps you to determine whether your game runs well on the majority of devices.

I thought sprite kit would be uniform across devices, and it is somewhat, but there are minor variations.